# Wordpress - Add a div around archive widget

Tags: wordpress, filter, widget, sidebar, action

I use Wordpress and have a sidebar containing widgets, run by this code:

```
<div class="sidebar modern">
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-modern' )) : ?>
        <ul>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-modern' ); ?>
        </ul>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**What I do in wp-admin**

1. I add the archive widget
2. I set display as a select-list (dropdown) in widget options

What I need is to add a container HTML class to the select.

**I have tried these and failed:**

- CSS (because it's a design thing)
- Filter - widget_archives_dropdown_args
- Filter - wp_get_archives filter

If it's possible to add a container class to all the widget inside (widget title not included), it would be fine by me.

Comment: For future googlers: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74732/adding-a-div-to-wrap-widget-content-after-the-widget-title for more answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible right now without editing the Wordpress core.

Comment: You really marked your answer as the correct one? Ulukai gave you the right answer.

Comment: No, not really. An uncomplete answer. It does not solve the problem completely. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Where you register the sidebar:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          =>  'Sidebar Modern',
    'id'            =>  'sidebar-modern',
    'before_widget' =>  '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s widget clearfix">',
    'after_widget'  =>  '</div>',
    'before_title'  =>  '<h3 class="title">',
    'after_title'   =>  '</h3>'
) );
```

Modify it like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          =>  'Sidebar Modern',
    'id'            =>  'sidebar-modern',
    'before_widget' =>  '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s widget clearfix">',
    'after_widget'  =>  '</div></div>',
    'before_title'  =>  '<h3 class="title">',
    'after_title'   =>  '</h3><div>'
) );
```

The key is the extra divs:

'after_widget' => '**</div>**</div>'
'after_title' => '</h3>**<div>**'

**EDIT:**

As **Ionut Staicu** pointed out, you can just do it like so:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          =>  'Sidebar Modern',
    'id'            =>  'sidebar-modern',
    'before_widget' =>  '<div><div id="%1$s" class="%2$s widget clearfix">',
    'after_widget'  =>  '</div></div>',
    'before_title'  =>  '<h3 class="title">',
    'after_title'   =>  '</h3>'
) );
```

Comment: This don't work with widgets that have no title set. The search widget can have no title for example.

Comment: if there is no title set, then you can simply add an extra div into `before_widget` & `after_widget`.

Comment: @lonut Staicu. I'm not sure how you mean. When setting up the register_sidebar the sidebar is set. It don't know what widgets there might be and what widgets have titles and which don't. Without title there is one open div tags and two closed div tags. Nesting problems. How is that solved adding an extra div to before_widget and after_widget?